# TRUE or FALSE: If a sequence converges to $0$, then it has a summable subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left( {{a_n}} \right)_{n = 1}^\infty $ be a sequence such that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } |{a_n}| = 0$. Prove that there are is subsequence ${a_{{n_k}}}$ so that $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{a_{{n_k}}}} $ converges.

**Proof**: Let $\left( {{a_n}} \right)_{n = 1}^\infty $ be a sequence and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } |{a_n}| = 0$ and ${a_{{n_k}}}$ be a subsequence.

Since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } |{a_n}| = 0$, let $\varepsilon  > 0$ , there is $N > 0$ so that 
    $$||a_n| - 0| < \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}},$$ that is $$|a_n| < \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}}$$
for all $n \geqslant N$ and $m,i \in N$ which $m > i.$

Consider subsequence ${a_{{n_k}}}$ , $k = i,i + 1,...,m - 1,m,[m - i{\text{ terms}}]$
Since $|{a_n}| < \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}}$ hence $$\begin{align}|{a_{{n_k}}}| &< \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}}|{a_{{n_{i + 1}}}} + {a_{{n_{i + 2}}}} + ... + {a_{{n_{m - 1}}}} + {a_{{n_m}}}|\\ &\leqslant |{a_{{n_{i + 1}}}}| + |{a_{{n_{i + 2}}}}| + ... + |{a_{{n_{m - 1}}}}| + |{a_{{n_m}}}|\\ &< \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}} + \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}} + ... + \frac{\varepsilon }{{m - i}}\\ &= \frac{{(m - i)\varepsilon }}{{m - i}}\\ &= \varepsilon\end{align}$$
$$\left|\sum_{k = i + 1}^m a_{n_k}\right|  < \varepsilon $$
By CAUCHY CRITERION FOR SERIES $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{a_{{n_k}}}} $ converges.

Comment: You can't have $|a_n| < {\epsilon \over m - i}$ as you are claiming... let $m = 2i$ and then let $m \rightarrow \infty$. Then $a_n = 0$.

Comment: Besides the many many typos, and the complete lack of punctuation, the argument makes no sense. Nothing in it can be saved, unfortunately. You need to prove that there is a subsequence with some property. Your first line in the proof cannot be "let $a_{n_k}$ be a subsequence". You then pick an $N$ with a very strong property, way beyond what the fact that the sequence converges to $0$ can ensure, and do not ever justify that this is possible. You then somehow assume that the indices of your subsequence are larger than $N$, even though $N$ was arbitrary, and nothing was done to ensure this.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: For every $n$ and $i$ there exists $k\geqslant n+1$ such that $|a_k|\leqslant1/2^i$. Show this fact, then use it recursively to exhibit an increasing sequence $(\varphi(n))$ such that $|a_{\varphi(n)}|\leqslant1/2^n$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, then your purported proof shows that every subsequence is summable, hence if it was correct it would show that every sequence converging to zero is summable. This is not the case.

A correct proof will start with a given sequence converging to zero and then show how to produce, *using properties of that particular sequence*, a subsequence which is summable, i.e. one which not only converges to zero but converges fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to show that *every* subsequence (of a sequence converging to $0$) has a convergent series, since the subsequence you're looking at is arbitrary. This is not true, though. Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac1n$.

Instead, try to proceed as follows: Pick your favorite convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k,$ where all the $b_k$ are positive. Now, construct a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $|a_{n_k}|<b_k$ for all $k$. You'll need to be a bit careful in your choices, since we need $n_1<n_2<n_3<...,$ but the fact that $a_n\to 0$ will make it possible. Why is it that we can conclude that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}$$ is convergent, then?